# Can't display JSON nested arrays with HTML table and PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I am trying to display the table that shows the latest vaccination data in each country. I managed to pull out the list of countries, but I could not display the nested arrays of the latest data, total vaccinated, and total vaccinations per hundred.

I want to display the array of `total_vaccinations` and `total_vaccinations_per_hundred` that contains the latest date value from `date`.

I am open to using jQuery and Javascript to make this work.

Here is the small section of the JSON data. The original data is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/vaccinations.json

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => Afghanistan
            [iso_code] => AFG
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-22
                            [total_vaccinations] => 0
                            [people_vaccinated] => 0
                            [total_vaccinations_per_hundred] => 0
                            [people_vaccinated_per_hundred] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-23
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-24
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-25
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-26
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-27
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-02-28
                            [total_vaccinations] => 8200
                            [people_vaccinated] => 8200
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1367
                            [total_vaccinations_per_hundred] => 0.02
                            [people_vaccinated_per_hundred] => 0.02
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 35
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-01
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1580
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 41
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-02
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 1794
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 46
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-03
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2008
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 52
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-04
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2221
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 57
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-05
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2435
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 63
                        )

                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-06
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2649
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 68
                        )

                    [13] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-07
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [14] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-08
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [15] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-09
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [16] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-10
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [17] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-11
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [18] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-12
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )

                    [19] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2021-03-13
                            [daily_vaccinations] => 2862
                            [daily_vaccinations_per_million] => 74
                        )
```

Small snipped of the HTML/PHP table

```
    <div class="container my-3 text-center">
      <h2 class="display-6">Vaccine Live Data</h2>
      <table class="table sortable" id="table" data-toggle="table">
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Countries</th>
            <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>
            <th scope="col">Total vaccinated</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Vaccinated Per Hundred</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <?php
                        foreach($data as $key => $info){
                    ?>
            <tr>
              <th class="sorttable_nosort">
                <?php echo $info['country']; ?>
              </th>

              <td data-order='desc' data-field="firstdose" data-sortable="true">
                <?php foreach($info['data'] as $key => $value) {  echo $value['date'];
     } ?>
              </td>

            </tr>

            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>



      </table>
    </div>
```

The current table output: [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5UJM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, is not finished. but you can take an idea.
Basically this script takes the last array of the country and display it, assuming that is the last updated. You can sort it with js table.

```
<div class="container my-3 text-center">
<h2 class="display-6">Vaccine Live Data</h2>
<table class="table sortable" id="table" data-toggle="table">
<thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
    <th scope="col">Countries</th>
    <th scope="col">Last Updated</th>
    <th scope="col">Total vaccinated</th>
    <th scope="col">Total Vaccinated Per Hundred</th>
    <th scope="col">People Vaccinated Per Hundred</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php foreach($data as $key => $info){
        $last_array = end($info["data"]);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="sorttable_nosort">
        <?php echo $info['country']; ?>
        </td>
        <td data-order='desc' data-field="firstdose" data-sortable="true">
            <?=$last_array["date"]?>
        </td>
        <td data-order='desc' data-field="firstdose" data-sortable="true">
            <?=$last_array["total_vaccinations"]?>
        </td>
        <td data-order='desc' data-field="firstdose" data-sortable="true">
            <?=$last_array["total_vaccinations_per_hundred"]?>
        </td>
        <td data-order='desc' data-field="firstdose" data-sortable="true">
            <?php
            if($last_array["people_vaccinated_per_hundred"]){
                echo $last_array["people_vaccinated_per_hundred"];
            }else{
                echo 'No data available';
            }
            ?>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
</tbody>



</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Your code has worked great except I have encountered `Warning: Undefined array key "people_vaccinated_per_hundred"` for the arrays that do not have `people_vaccinated_per_hundred`. How do I insert the if statement for the array to display "Data not available" if an array doesn't contain `people_vaccinated_per_hundred`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the if-statement still shows the same error, however, I was able to solve it with the following code: <?php
        
                        if (array_key_exists("people_vaccinated_per_hundred",$last_array))
                        {
                            echo $last_array["people_vaccinated_per_hundred"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo 'No dispone de datos';
                        }
                        ?>

Comment: que raro a mi si me funciona, podria ser la version de php. pero igual tu forma esta correcta!